# Irregular div background, with responsive layout

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following image:

http://i47.tinypic.com/219zkl.png

That needs to be the background for a .four-columns div in the Foundation framework. The div headline needs to be in the black ribbon, and the content in the box below.

The problem I'm having is getting the background to behave properly as the grid is resized in the browser. I don't want to write loads of media queries just for this background. I've tried using the background-size:cover property, but this leads to it looking horribly pixelated on the phone, and not covering the div correctly on tablet sizes. I've also tried absolute positioning, but that hasn't worked either.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This background is too simple to use an image. Just go with pure CSS.

If you have trouble to produce angled borders, here is a simple tutorial>
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

Comment: For some reason this never occurred to me - I just drew a pure-CSS responsive ribbon, and it worked no problem. Cheers!